# URLOpen error during Web Service communication

Tags: python, web-services, suds

I had to developed an application which will communicate with a Web service via python. I have to run this code on a Windows server machine for some reasons (which i am not much experianced with, notmally we use uint based systems).

My communication with the api provider is not directly because of some communication issies. So i have to mail my problems to another person and he email them my message in the native language, so i could not get much support from the provider because of that.

My problem is, i use `suds` for web service client. Cleint semmed to succeed to get WSDL definition from the serveer like:

```
from suds.client import Client

class SomeClass(Client):
    def __init__(self):
        Client.__init__(url)

def myFunc():
    f = SomeClass()
    print f
```

> Service ( transport ) tns="..."
>
> Prefixes (1) ns0 = ....
>
> ```
> Ports (2):
>
>     (TransportSoap) 
>
>          Methods (4) 
>
>              GetBalance()
> ```
>
> ...

So i can see that `suds` can reach target web service and get the WSDL file. However when i call a method like:

```
def myFunc():
    f = SomeClass()    
    f.GetBalance()


Urllib2.URLError <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
period of time, or established connection failed because connected
host has failed to respond>
```

I could not see what is wrong?

Comment: May be the endpoint expects SSL and SUDS default transport is plain HTTP - hard to tell without inspecting the WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search based on `urlopen error [Errno 10060]`, i decided to try **proxy usage** and it turns out to be the solution!

If WSDL url is

> http://someurl.com:1234/something/somethingmore.asmx?WSDL

then using:

```
prxy = dict(http='http://someurl.com:1234/')
Client.set_options(proxy=prxy)
```

definitely solves the problem...